# Customers can't login with chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, chrome-browser

Im not sure why, but customers can login with firefox but not with chrome. If I try to login with chrome, then the site just reloads and nothing changed.

There is no error, what can I try?

Comment: Try it in private browser.

Comment: I restarted the browser, now it works again... not sure what was going on

Comment: That was something related to cookie or session.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that your theme does not supply a variable called form_key.

Just as stated above I have to add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

you add it right after `<ul class="form-list">`

to each one of my login.phtml files for the theme.

Comment: There is a form key.

Comment: it is already added. Still i am facing issue..

Answer (score 0):

Default cookie time is 3600 sec  please make it  1 day
From your admin

It's magento's default cookie time out issue

Comment: I have set it to 0 so it lasts until the browser is getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of Magento with Chrome browser, especially when you are using the localhost environment. 
To get rid of this problem, update your base url and secure base url to your local IP instead of localhost.

ie change the base url and secure base url from `http://localhost/yourproject/`
to `http://yourlocalipaddress/yourproject/`.

Eg: `http://127.0.0.1/yourproject/`.